# Android - Close IME settings activity after user has enabled input method

Tags: android, input, keyboard, settings, ime

How can I close the IME settings activity (ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS) after the user has enabled a specific IME (or maybe just any ime if that's the only possibility) just like the Google Keyboard does.

I've tried both:

```
Intent enableIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS);
        //enableIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        activity.startActivityForResult(enableIntent, 0);
```

and:

```
Intent enableIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS);
        enableIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(enableIntent);
```

But it isn't able to return to the calling activity once an item is selected/enabled.

The google keyboard opens the IME input settings screen and as soon as the keyboard is enabled (check box clicked), the settings activity closes and the user is returned to the prior wizard activity.

Comment: No, I thought of a way but haven't tested it.
You can easily detect once the keyboard has been enabled, so once this happens you call your activity back to the front

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a hard time trying to solve this problem as well. Until I realized that I could just check the AOSP implementation [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME). Specifically, checkout the [SetupWizardActivity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/marshmallow-release/java/src/com/android/inputmethod/latin/setup/SetupWizardActivity.java). What it looks like to me is that Google spins up a `Handler` which will poll for the state. Specifically, try to follow `SettingsPoolingHandler#handleMessage`

**Specifically:**

```
    step1.setAction(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            invokeLanguageAndInputSettings();
            handler.startPollingImeSettings();
        }
    });


    public void startPollingImeSettings() {
        sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(MSG_POLLING_IME_SETTINGS),
                IME_SETTINGS_POLLING_INTERVAL);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(final Message msg) {
        final SetupWizardActivity setupWizardActivity = getOwnerInstance();
        if (setupWizardActivity == null) {
            return;
        }
        switch (msg.what) {
        case MSG_POLLING_IME_SETTINGS:
            if (UncachedInputMethodManagerUtils.isThisImeEnabled(setupWizardActivity,
                    mImmInHandler)) {
                setupWizardActivity.invokeSetupWizardOfThisIme();
                return;
            }
            startPollingImeSettings();
            break;
        }
    }


    void invokeSetupWizardOfThisIme() {
       final Intent intent = new Intent();
       intent.setClass(this, SetupWizardActivity.class);
       intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED
               | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
               | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
       startActivity(intent);
       mNeedsToAdjustStepNumberToSystemState = true;
   }
```

Comment: nice, it's basically what I suggested